# Firebase cloud messaging with database triggers

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

Hi there fellow programmers. I'm developing a mobile app using firebase and I want a push notification to be sent to all users when a particular value in realtime database.

After some searching I figured I probably have to use cloud functions and database triggers. So since I have no knowledge of node.js I need someone to help me through this (like any half-ready code or anything like that)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following sample?

- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications